Not able to login into my MS enterprise license on MAC VSCode
VS Code version details:
Version: 1.94.0 (Universal)
Commit: d78a74bcdfad14d5d3b1b782f87255d802b57511
Date: 2024-10-02T13:08:12.626Z
Electron: 30.5.1
ElectronBuildId: 10262041
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.16.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.5.0

Steps:

Login to my MS account by clicking UserProfile

Sign in with Microsoft to use C# dev kit

Opens Browser and asks me to login

After login browser redirects me to 127.0.0.1:port

in vs output I get this message

[error] [/.default VSCODE_CLIENT_ID: VSCODE_TENANT:common email offline_access openid profile] Error creating session: Error: Network failure

I have masked <GUID> values



Are you able to try out VS Code Insider build to see if it works (a known issue has just been fixed https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/226662)?
